# attributes value change using ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, fckeditor

I want to make plug-in in CKEditor. When I select text partially and click on the plug-in button it put custom tag on the selected text.Mention code works accordingly. However the attributes of unselected text changes

```
var selection = editor.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRanges();
var cdlToc=editor.document.createElement('cdl:toc');
var pageNumber = parseInt($('#hiddenPageNumber').val());
cdlToc.setAttribute("pageNumber", pageNumber);
cdlToc.setStyle( 'color', 'blue' );
var extractedContent = range[0].extractContents(false);
var test=editor.document.createElement('test');
test.append(extractedContent)
var childCount=test.getChildCount();
 for(var i=0; i < childCount; i++){
  var child=test.getChild(i);
  if(child.getName()=='p')
    cdlToc.appendHtml(child.getHtml());
  else
     cdlToc.appendHtml(child.getOuterHtml());
 }

var paragraph=editor.document.createElement('p');  
paragraph.appendHtml(cdlToc.getOuterHtml());
paragraph.unselectable();
selection.selectRanges(range[0]);
editor.insertHtml(paragraph.getOuterHtml());
```

**before inserting tags Source Code looks**

```
<p><cdl:metadata fname="OFAZVP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtCn" fsize="10.0" pagenumber="1" x="499.954" y="37.493">Research</cdl:metadata></p>
<p><cdl:metadata fname="OFAZVP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtCnO" fsize="8.0" pagenumber="1" x="56.693" y="805.104">Bull World Health Organ</cdl:metadata><cdl:metadata fname="OFAZVP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtCn" fsize="8.0" pagenumber="1" x="124.044" y="805.104"> 2010;88:887&#x2013;896G </cdl:metadata><cdl:metadata fname="OFAZVP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-HvEx" fsize="12.0" pagenumber="1" x="186.099" y="805.104">|</cdl:metadata><cdl:metadata fname="OFAZVP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtCn" fsize="8.0" pagenumber="1" x="188.763" y="805.104"> doi:10.2471/BLT.09.071852</cdl:metadata></p>
<p><cdl:metadata fname="PNKFJN+HelveticaNeueLTStd-BdCn" fsize="13.0" pagenumber="1" x="56.693" y="367.697">Introduction</cdl:metadata></p>
```

**after inserting tags**

```
<p><cdl:metadata fname="PNKFJN+HelveticaNeueLTStd-BdCn" fsize="13.0" pagenumber="1" x="56.693" y="367.697">Rese</cdl:metadata></p>
<p style="-moz-user-select: none;"><cdl:toc pagenumber="1" style="color: blue;"><cdl:metadata fname="OFAZVP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtCn" fsize="10.0" pagenumber="1" x="499.954" y="37.493">arch</cdl:metadata><br />
<cdl:metadata fname="OFAZVP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtCnO" fsize="8.0" pagenumber="1" x="56.693" y="805.104">Bull World Health Organ</cdl:metadata><cdl:metadata fname="OFAZVP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtCn" fsize="8.0" pagenumber="1" x="124.044" y="805.104"> 2010;88:887&#x2013;896G </cdl:metadata><cdl:metadata fname="OFAZVP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-HvEx" fsize="12.0" pagenumber="1" x="186.099" y="805.104">|</cdl:metadata><cdl:metadata fname="OFAZVP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtCn" fsize="8.0" pagenumber="1" x="188.763" y="805.104"> doi:10.2471/BLT.09.071852</cdl:metadata><br />
<cdl:metadata fname="PNKFJN+HelveticaNeueLTStd-BdCn" fsize="13.0" pagenumber="1" x="56.693" y="367.697">Introdu</cdl:metadata></cdl:toc></p>
<p><cdl:metadata fname="PNKFJN+HelveticaNeueLTStd-BdCn" fsize="13.0" pagenumber="1" x="56.693" y="367.697">ction</cdl:metadata></p>
```

If i use
    editor.insertElement(paragraph);
instead of
    editor.insertHtml(paragraph.getOuterHtml()); 
then output is (delete p tag from Res)

```
 <p><cdl:metadata fname="PNKFJN+HelveticaNeueLTStd-BdCn" fsize="8.0" pagenumber="1" x="527.063" y="805.082">887</cdl:metadata><cdl:metadata fname="OFAZVP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtCn" fsize="10.0" pagenumber="1" x="499.954" y="37.493">Res</cdl:metadata></p>
<p style="-moz-user-select: none;"><cdl:toc pagenumber="1" style="color: blue;"><cdl:metadata fname="OFAZVP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtCn" fsize="10.0" pagenumber="1" x="499.954" y="37.493">earch</cdl:metadata><br />
<cdl:metadata fname="OFAZVP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtCnO" fsize="8.0" pagenumber="1" x="56.693" y="805.104">Bull World Health Organ</cdl:metadata><cdl:metadata fname="OFAZVP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtCn" fsize="8.0" pagenumber="1" x="124.044" y="805.104"> 2010;88:887&#x2013;896G </cdl:metadata><cdl:metadata fname="OFAZVP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-HvEx" fsize="12.0" pagenumber="1" x="186.099" y="805.104">|</cdl:metadata><cdl:metadata fname="OFAZVP+HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtCn" fsize="8.0" pagenumber="1" x="188.763" y="805.104"> doi:10.2471/BLT.09.071852</cdl:metadata><cdl:metadata fname="PNKFJN+HelveticaNeueLTStd-BdCn" fsize="13.0" pagenumber="1" x="56.693" y="367.697">Introd</cdl:metadata></cdl:toc></p>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: my question is why and how attibute change while using editor.insertHtml(paragraph.getOuterHtml()) and why p tag of  two element nodes merge or say p delete while using editor.insertElement(paragraph);

Comment: Is there any way of simplifying the situation so we don't have to read all that? Like can you duplicate the issue with just `<p>FOO</p><p><metadata x="1">BAR</metadata></p><p>BAZ</p>`? Doing a manual DIFF with that data... computer says no. Think of this as if you were writing a bug report and try to find the simplest possible situation where you can duplicate your issue - you will get answers much easier that way.